# Google Maps API Missing Locations

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

We have found a bit of an issue with the Google Maps API, in which places such as Chiswick are missing when searching under the types: ['(cities)'] options.

```
var options = {
                                language: 'en-GB',
                                types: ['(cities)'],
                                componentRestrictions: {country: "gb"}
                            };
```

We can get really granular and get down to villages, which is perfect for what we want it to do, such items are Bishop Middleham appear fine, then moving up to Durham, Newcastle, Middlesbrough are fine, but it seems to fall short for places like Chiswick above (which is a region of London).

The next region along from Chiswick is Brentford, which works fine on the API, as does Acton, as does Hanwell, and Hammersmith is a little different appearing as (London Borough of Hammersmith and Fulham).

It seems suburbs may be missing in its full extent?

The only way I can seem to get Chiswick to appear is if I go down to Street Level, which is something we don't want to appear.

Has anyone else come across this issue?

Here's the code in JSFiddle - https://jsfiddle.net/3373x9mj/

Answer (score 1):

If you compare the features of [Chiswick](https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&iwloc=0_0&dtab=history&cid=14424775999983204077) and [Brentford](https://mapmaker.google.com/mapmaker?gw=90&iwloc=0_0&dtab=history&cid=15901812698801685335) in Map Maker, you will see that Chiswick has a category 'Sub-Locality / Neighborhood' while Brentford has a category 'City / Town / Village'.

My guess is that sub-localities are filtered out once you apply `types: ['(cities)']` filter.

Probably, this is a data issue. You can use the "Report a problem" link to let the Google data team know about this issue.

https://support.google.com/maps/answer/162873

Hope it helps!

Comment: I thought that was the case when I was testing and noticed the same, but thought I was doing something wrong - I have submitted a bug report on the Google Maps API page - see what they come back with.